# Fault Tolerant Action Server Client Design?

Tags: ros-humble, python3, errors, action-client, fastdds

My ROS 2 Humble Create3 robot Dock action client sometimes does not receive a dock action  result (callback sometimes not called).  The robot log shows the action goal succeeded, and my client node knows the action succeeded via the /dock_status.is_docked topic but often not via the dock action result callback.

The bot and client both have FastDDS configured.  I don't know how to debug the lost or never published result, so it seems that I need a fault tolerant design for action servers - perhaps setting a timeout timer callback when the goal is accepted, that is cancelled if the result is received?

This is my client code:

```
 def dock_action_send_goal(self):
    # dock_msg = DockServo.Goal()
    dock_msg = Dock.Goal()
    if DEBUG:
      dtstr = dt.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
      printMsg = "dock_action_send_goal(): executing"
      print(dtstr, printMsg)
    self._dock_action_client.wait_for_server()
    if DEBUG:
        dtstr = dt.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        print(dtstr, "dock_action_send_goal(): after wait_for_server()")
    self._dock_action_send_goal_future = self._dock_action_client.send_goal_async(dock_msg)
    if DEBUG:
        dtstr = dt.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        print(dtstr, "dock_action_send_goal(): after set future")
    self._dock_action_send_goal_future.add_done_callback(self.dock_goal_response_callback)
    if DEBUG:
        dtstr = dt.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        print(dtstr, "dock_action_send_goal(): after add_done_callback")

  def dock_goal_response_callback(self, future):
    goal_handle = future.result()
    if DEBUG:
      dtstr = dt.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
      printMsg = "dock_goal_response_callback(): Goal Accepted: {}".format(goal_handle.accepted)
      print(dtstr, printMsg)

    if not goal_handle.accepted:
      printMsg = 'dock Goal Rejected'
      self.get_logger().info(printMsg)
      if DEBUG:
          dtstr = dt.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
          print(dtstr, printMsg)
      return

    printMsg = 'dock Goal Accepted'
    self.get_logger().info(printMsg)
    if DEBUG:
        dtstr = dt.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        print(dtstr, printMsg)

    self.state = "docking"

    self._get_dock_result_future = goal_handle.get_result_async()
    self._get_dock_result_future.add_done_callback(self.get_dock_result_callback)

  def get_dock_result_callback(self, future):
    result = future.result().result
    if DEBUG:
      dtstr = dt.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
      printMsg = "get_dock_result_callback(): dock Result is_docked {} %".format(result.is_docked)
      print(dtstr, printMsg)
    if result.is_docked:
      dtstr = dt.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
      self.state = "docked"
      printMsg = "** WaLI Docking: success at battery {:.0f}% **".format(self.battery_percentage*100)
      self.lifeLog.info(printMsg)
      if DEBUG:
          dtstr = dt.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
          print(dtstr, printMsg)
    else:
      self.state = "undocked"
      printMsg = "** WaLi Docking: failed **"
      self.lifeLog.info(printMsg)
      if DEBUG:
          dtstr = dt.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
          print(dtstr, printMsg)
```

This is the robot log for the goal:

```
Jan  8 12:47:34 Create3-WaLi user.notice create-platform: [INFO] [1704718054.227311720] [motion_control]: Received new dock servo goal
Jan  8 12:47:34 Create3-WaLi user.notice create-platform: [INFO] [1704718054.228529119] [motion_control]: {Dock SM} constructed
Jan  8 12:47:34 Create3-WaLi user.notice create-platform: [INFO] [1704718054.228890902] [motion_control]: {Dock SM} dock sent docking params packet initial pass
Jan  8 12:47:34 Create3-WaLi user.notice create-platform: [INFO] [1704718054.238709282] [motion_control]: digital_sensor_msi_listener: m_is_config_active 1
Jan  8 12:47:34 Create3-WaLi user.notice create-platform: [INFO] [1704718054.239130471] [motion_control]: Received 1 digital sensor packets
Jan  8 12:47:34 Create3-WaLi user.notice create-platform: [INFO] [1704718054.278072540] [motion_control]: {Dock SM} Running DOCK_PROTO_SEND_CONFIG
Jan  8 12:47:34 Create3-WaLi user.notice create-platform: [INFO] [1704718054.278461871] [motion_control]: {Dock SM} dock: DOCK_PROTO_SEND_CONFIG -->> DOCK_PROTO_WAIT_CONFIG
Jan  8 12:47:34 Create3-WaLi user.notice create-platform: [INFO] [1704718054.328515114] [motion_control]: {Dock SM} config received; start dock
Jan  8 12:47:34 Create3-WaLi user.notice create-platform: [INFO] [1704718054.328880455] [motion_control]: {Dock SM} dock: DOCK_PROTO_WAIT_CONFIG -->> DOCK_PROTO_RUNNING
Jan  8 12:47:34 Create3-WaLi user.notice create-platform: [INFO] [1704718054.378040726] [motion_control]: {Dock SM} dock mob behavior started
Jan  8 12:47:36 Create3-WaLi user.notice create-platform: [INFO] [1704718056.255000956] [motion_control]: Received 127 digital sensor packets
Jan  8 12:47:36 Create3-WaLi user.notice create-platform: [INFO] [1704718056.278086008] [motion_control]: {Dock SM} Running DOCK_PROTO_RUNNING
Jan  8 12:47:38 Create3-WaLi user.notice create-platform: [INFO] [1704718058.255217336] [motion_control]: Received 252 digital sensor packets
Jan  8 12:47:38 Create3-WaLi user.notice create-platform: [INFO] [1704718058.278092968] [motion_control]: {Dock SM} Running DOCK_PROTO_RUNNING
Jan  8 12:47:39 Create3-WaLi user.notice create-platform: [INFO] [1704718059.987127689] [root_ble_interface]: New bump state 64
Jan  8 12:47:40 Create3-WaLi user.notice create-platform: [INFO] [1704718060.271373290] [motion_control]: Received 378 digital sensor packets
Jan  8 12:47:40 Create3-WaLi user.notice create-platform: [INFO] [1704718060.278993536] [motion_control]: {Dock SM} Running DOCK_PROTO_RUNNING
Jan  8 12:47:40 Create3-WaLi user.notice create-platform: [INFO] [1704718060.485704803] [_internal.mobility]: Received IMU dcd request
Jan  8 12:47:40 Create3-WaLi user.notice create-platform: [INFO] [1704718060.487057774] [mobility_monitor]: Saved IMU Cal after docking with 11765.600352 seconds off the dock
Jan  8 12:47:40 Create3-WaLi user.notice create-platform: [INFO] [1704718060.994291257] [motion_control]: Received 1 docking status packets
Jan  8 12:47:41 Create3-WaLi user.notice create-platform: [WARN] [1704718061.028515456] [motion_control]: {Dock SM} dock mob behavior stopped unexpectedly
Jan  8 12:47:41 Create3-WaLi user.notice create-platform: [INFO] [1704718061.029315488] [motion_control]: {Dock SM} dock: DOCK_PROTO_RUNNING -->> DOCK_PROTO_GET_STATUS
Jan  8 12:47:41 Create3-WaLi user.notice create-platform: [INFO] [1704718061.078529669] [motion_control]: {Dock SM} got dock status back
Jan  8 12:47:41 Create3-WaLi user.notice create-platform: [INFO] [1704718061.079270950] [motion_control]: {Dock SM} dock: DOCK_PROTO_GET_STATUS -->> DOCK_PROTO_WAIT_DONE
Jan  8 12:47:42 Create3-WaLi user.notice create-platform: [INFO] [1704718062.271969464] [motion_control]: Received 503 digital sensor packets
Jan  8 12:47:42 Create3-WaLi user.notice create-platform: [INFO] [1704718062.328273497] [motion_control]: {Dock SM} Running DOCK_PROTO_WAIT_DONE
Jan  8 12:47:43 Create3-WaLi user.notice create-platform: [WARN] [1704718063.128114801] [motion_control]: {Dock SM} timed out packet response
Jan  8 12:47:43 Create3-WaLi user.notice create-platform: [INFO] [1704718063.128478236] [motion_control]: {Dock SM} stop behavior with result 0
Jan  8 12:47:43 Create3-WaLi user.notice create-platform: [INFO] [1704718063.130067675] [motion_control]: Dock Servo Goal Succeeded
Jan  8 12:47:43 Create3-WaLi user.notice create-platform: [INFO] [1704718063.183104048] [motion_control]: digital_sensor_msi_listener: m_is_config_active 0
Jan  8 12:48:28 Create3-WaLi user.notice create-platform: [INFO] [1704718108.891626778] [system_health]: CPU usage: max 74 [%] mean 58 [%] RAM usage: 39/59 [MB]
```

This is my client log:

```
2024-01-08 07:40|wali_node.py| ** WaLI Ready To Dock at battery 17% **
2024-01-08 07:48|[logMaintenance.py.main]** Dock goal result not received - Docking: success  **
```

## Can someone point me to a "Fault Tolerant" action client example?